# Spring Boot CORS not working even after @CrossOrigin annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cors

I have the following code that handles a CORS request

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", methods = RequestMethod.PUT)
@RequestMapping(value = "/componentOrder", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody List<Map<String, Long>> syncComponentOrder(@PathVariable Long id,
        @RequestBody List<Map<String, Long>> orders) { ... }
```

Even though Spring documentation says that this should handle a CORS request correctly but my Chrome still reports an error:

[image: why is it internal server error?]
[image: detailed error message]

I need some help finding out why, the other CORS endpoints work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out why, this is not because the `@CrossOrigin` annotation, but rather I was missing a path parameter in my request, that's why I saw `internal server error`.

Strangely no error/warning is printed out, making it hard to debug.